# SQLAlchemy - copy schema and data of subquery to another database

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to copy data from a subquery from postgres (from_engine) to sqlite database.  I can achieve this for copying a table using following command:

```
smeta = MetaData(bind=from_engine)
table = Table(table_name, smeta, autoload=True)
table.metadata.create_all(to_engine)
```

However, I am not sure how to achieve the same for a subquery statement.

-Sandeep

Edit:
Follow up on the answer.  Once I have created the table I want to create a subquery stmt as follows:

```
table = Table("newtable", dest_metadata, *columns)
stmt = dest_session.query(table).subquery();
```

However, the last stmt ends up with error
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) relation "newtable" does not exist
LINE 3: FROM newtable) AS anon_1

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you'd like to achive? Would you like to create a table with the scheme & data of a query result? I don't understand how a subquery comes into play.

Comment: Stefan, Yes I would like to create a table and fill it with query result. Consider a query that does filter on a single attribute (i.e. projection and selection). I want to create a table that would have only one attribute and results of the selection i.e. the schema of the results from the subquery as oppose to the original tables on which that query was done. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sandeep this sounds like the exact case for having a view, like simply creating a view based on the query results&schema and then treat that view as the table itself. SQLAlchemy does not support creating views out of the box but it's relatively easy to add your own support for it, check out https://gist.github.com/techniq/5174412 for a view implementation and http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/ddl.html on how to integrate it to SQLAlchemy. If this makes sense I can expand it into a full proper answer

Comment: @gts it is good to be able to create a view. What I want is more than creating a view. Essentially copying over the schema and results to another instance of a database.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

One way that works at least in some cases:

1. Use `column_descriptions` of a query object to get some information about the columns in the result set.
2. With that information you can build the schema to create the new table in the other database.
3. Run the query in the source database and insert the results into the new table.

First of some setup for the example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, 
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Engine to the database to query the data from
# (postgresql)
source_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
SourceSession = sessionmaker(source_engine)

# Engine to the database to store the results in
# (sqlite)
dest_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
DestSession = sessionmaker(dest_engine)

# Create some toy table and fills it with some data
Base = declarative_base()
class Pet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pets'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    race = Column(String)

Base.metadata.create_all(source_engine)
sourceSession = SourceSession()
sourceSession.add(Pet(name="Fido", race="cat"))
sourceSession.add(Pet(name="Ceasar", race="cat"))
sourceSession.add(Pet(name="Rex", race="dog"))
sourceSession.commit()
```

Now to the interesting bit:

```
# This is the query we want to persist in a new table:
query= sourceSession.query(Pet.name, Pet.race).filter_by(race='cat')

# Build the schema for the new table
# based on the columns that will be returned 
# by the query:
metadata = MetaData(bind=dest_engine)
columns = [Column(desc['name'], desc['type']) for desc in query.column_descriptions]
column_names = [desc['name'] for desc in query.column_descriptions]
table = Table("newtable", metadata, *columns)

# Create the new table in the destination database
table.create(dest_engine)

# Finally execute the query
destSession = DestSession()
for row in query:
    destSession.execute(table.insert(row))
destSession.commit()
```

There should be more efficient ways to do the last loop. But bulk-insert is another topic.

Comment: Great!. Thank you so much. I have one outstanding issue. When I perform subquery on the table object it gives me error relation newtable does not exits: Let me add the offending line in my reply. In case you happen to know what could cause these let me know.

Comment: After creating the table object, but before you use the table in a query, it has to be created in the database using `table.create(dest_engine)`. This will actually execute the "CREATE TABLE" SQL command. See also the code in my example.

Comment: I do call the table.create(dest_engine). Maybe I should put this as a separate question on SO.

Comment: I think I need to see more of the code to give you any help. I don't understand why you're using subquery in the first place. A new question will give you more attention. This question is for a very specific problem that seems to frighten SO users away :)

Comment: I think I somewhat understand what is causing the problem. The newtable is not bound to any class. Usually, I do session.query(<name_of_class>). For newtable there is no class it is bound to. Essentially, the question is how do I query newtable now?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I'm sure there is a way to query using the `Table` instance. I'd open another question for it. There are quite a lot of SQLAlchemy users here on stackoverflow. Someone is bound to know it.

Comment: Just wanted to say that I figured out the answer for querying the table instance. One can create a dynamic class and use classical mapping to link the table with the class

Comment: Bulk add isn't that complicated:
destSession.add_all(list_of_rows)

Comment: This answer also of use outside of a query context, e.g. coding our own schema migrations.  Combine with this page/section to help get to the column data from wherever you're starting from: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#accessing-tables-and-columns#accessing-tables-and-columns

Comment: comment on bulk insert: in order to run destSession.add_all(list_of_rows) the _sa_instance_state on each result row must be reset to 'transient' by running: [sqlalchemy.orm.session.make_transient(row) for row in list_of_rows].

Answer (score 6):

You can also go through a pandas data frame. For example a method would use `pandas.read_sql(query, source.connection)` and `df.to_sql(table_name, con=destination.connection)`.

Comment: to_sql() method does not capture the relationships among the tables.

Comment: Above is not the right way, how you will handle data types in panda dataframe with above code?

Comment: For sure `df.to_sql()` is only a workaround if you want to copy a rough data structure. You need [table.create](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.create)() to properly create data types, foreign keys and indexes in the destination database. Then you can send the data with `df.to_sql(name=table_name,con=destination.connection, if_exists="append")` in append mode.